The way to synchronously load html (with Swift) from URL just like user see
I'm looking for the most straight-forward way to get the FULL html from a page. After page load and after JS will finish work.
Speed is not important. Optimization is not important. Locking of main thread is not important.
Only the result is important: get the full HTML code of the page. Synchronously.

I'm tried to get html with WKWebView:
class InternetLoader {
    private let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
    
    private let script = """
    window.onload = function() {
        document.body.innerHTML;
    };
    """
    
    private var resultHtml: String? = nil
    
    func getHTML(from url: URL) -> String {
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(script) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error executing JavaScript: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if let htmlContent = result as? String {
                self.resultHtml = htmlContent
            }
            
            semaphore.signal()
        }
        
        semaphore.wait()
        
        return resultHtml!
    }
}


Usage:
let il = InternetLoader()
let html = il.getHTML(from: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions"))

But it endlessly stuck.
what I'm doing wrong?

Can you show an example of a URL where you are not getting the "FULL html"? Show what you got, and what the "FULL html" should be.

@Sweeper "Оригінальна назва:" (original name) block from page: "https://anitube.in.ua/4745-mstika-dvchata-tayemnich-zniknennya.html" but I'm sure it is inaccessible from all countries except Ukraine.

It is NOT DUPLICATE of those question.  Please, vote to reopen.

I can access the website just fine, but I can't find "Оригінальна назва" on that page. I will reopen if I can verify that didFinish indeed cannot get the HTML you want.

@Sweeper https://prnt.sc/Hqvxzh4lsKQA

It would help if you explained why you think those other questions are not a duplicate. They do answer your question as written. Without more details, there's no reason to think otherwise.

@HangarRash 1) For me it is not important what I will use: WKWebView or sth another. 2) In my question I'm using almost the same way as in those answers; 3) All I need to get synchroniusly (most straight-forward way) full HTML code from URL. Those answers are not.

@Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA Those other answers work. Why not adapt one to suit your needs? If you have some bizarre need for it to be synchronous, you can easily adapt one of the async solutions to be synchronous. Having your question reopened seems inappropriate.

@HangarRash, but that's exactly what I'm trying to do from the beginning, and you're closing my question. It's not easy for me to adapt those answers, it's easy FOR YOU to adapt those answers. But not for me. Because of both of us have different experience in different things. If you're not trying to help, at least don't interfere. PLEASE. Just leave this question unanswered and I will create a bounty in a few days and someone other will help.

@Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA I was not interfering. Based on your question, as written, those other answers do answer your question which is why it was original closed. It's only later, in your comments, that you have made it clear that having a synchronous wrapper around the async solution is a requirement. You need to update your question to make that clear. I'm actually trying to help by getting you to make your question clear. Please do not mistake that for interfering.

Actually, I am still unable to find "Оригінальна назва" on that page, even with an Ukraine VPN. However, using this answer, I was at least able to get the title "Містика, дівчата і таємничі зникнення".

@Sweeper can you share your code with github gist?

@Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA from where and when you are creating let il = InternetLoader(), after user interaction with a button or something else?

@Immanuel just an console app.

Thanks to wkwebview in command line. Modified this to get html
@MainActor
class InternetLoader: NSObject {
    
    lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
        let webView: WKWebView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        return webView
    }()
    
    private var resultHtml: String? = nil
        
    var continuation: UnsafeContinuation<String?, Error>?
    
    func getHTML(from url: URL) async throws -> String? {
        return try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            self.continuation = continuation
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }
    
}

extension InternetLoader: WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerHTML") { [weak self] (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error executing JavaScript: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if let htmlContent = result as? String {
                self?.resultHtml = htmlContent
            }
            self?.continuation?.resume(returning: self?.resultHtml)
        }
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        continuation?.resume(throwing: error)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        continuation?.resume(throwing: error)
    }
}


let loader = InternetLoader()
var html = ""
if let confirmedHtml = try? await loader.getHTML(from: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions")!) {
    html = confirmedHtml
}
print(html)


It works good, it's getting much accurate html code. But this is async func instead of sync =( When you fix it to sync code I will give you 150 vote points. Thanks for your help

@Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA web view needs some time for loading the content.
if let confirmedHtml = try? await loader.getHTML(from: URL... this code will not go to next line until the web view loads or fails.

I know what means sync and async :) Thats why I requested help with exactly sync function in question :) And thats why I have tried to write sync func with semaphore.wait():)

I think Immanuel's answer using async/await is good. You can create a command-line tool where the main() method of the @main struct is async, and then use his solution.
However, since it seems important that the method is synchronous, I made an attempt using an OperationQueue and a RunLoop.
The problem with the code in the question is that waiting for the semaphore is causing a deadlock, because the completion handler for evaluateJavascript is always executed on the main thread. Since semaphore.wait() blocks the main thread, the signal is never called.
In my solution, I created asyncronous operations and then used a run loop to let them all execute in the correct order.
enum OpStatus {
    case initial, executing, finished
}

class AsyncOp: Operation {
    var opStatus: OpStatus = .initial {
        willSet {
            willChangeValue(for: \.isExecuting)
            willChangeValue(for: \.isFinished)
        }
        didSet {
            didChangeValue(for: \.isExecuting)
            didChangeValue(for: \.isFinished)
        }
    }
    override var isAsynchronous: Bool { true }
    override var isExecuting: Bool { opStatus == .executing }
    override var isFinished: Bool { opStatus == .finished }
}

final class LoadOp: AsyncOp, WKNavigationDelegate {
    private let url: URL
    private let webView: WKWebView
    
    init(url: URL, webView: WKWebView) {
        self.url = url
        self.webView = webView
        super.init()
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
    }
    
    override func start() {
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        opStatus = .executing
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        opStatus = .finished
    }
}

final class JSOp: AsyncOp {
    var resultHtml: String?
    private let webView: WKWebView
    private let script: String
    
    init(webView: WKWebView, script: String) {
        self.webView = webView
        self.script = script
        super.init()
    }
    
    override func start() {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(script) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error executing JavaScript: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if let htmlContent = result as? String {
                self.resultHtml = htmlContent
            }
            self.opStatus = .finished
        }
        opStatus = .executing
    }
}

final class InternetLoader {
    private let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
    private let script = "document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString();"
    
    func getHTML(from url: URL) -> String? {
        var jsLoaded = false
        var isQueueSetup = false
        
        let opQueue = OperationQueue.main
        opQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        
        let loadOp = LoadOp(url: url, webView: webView)
        let jsOp = JSOp(webView: webView, script: script)
        jsOp.addDependency(loadOp)
        jsOp.completionBlock = {
            jsLoaded = true
        }
        
        while !jsLoaded && RunLoop.main.run(mode: .default, before: .distantFuture) {
            if !isQueueSetup {
                opQueue.addOperations([loadOp, jsOp], waitUntilFinished: false)
                isQueueSetup = true
            }
        }
        
        return jsOp.resultHtml
    }
}

let il = InternetLoader()
let html = il.getHTML(from: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions")!)
print(String(describing: html))

This is a lot of code, but it works. It still needs more error handling for the web view, and you should ensure that this is an appropriate use of RunLoop, which I'm not that experienced with, it can probably serve as a good starting point.

Thank you very much! Can I give 150 points to Immanuel, even if you gave the synchronized answer? As you gave sync answer I will let you choose who will get bounty.

It is your question, you decide! I will not be upset if you choose the other answer and it works in your use case, as I am a proponent of adapting async/await wherever it is sensible to do so.
